# Avoiding IllegalArgumentException when using NULL as placeholder value in query?

Tags: java, android, cursor

I'm trying to get contacts photo from content providers and facing some kind of issue with this query.

```
Cursor photo = cr.query( 
                   PicURI,  
                   new String[] {
                      CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO
                   }, 
                   Data._ID + "=?",  
                   new String[] { photoId }, 
                   null);
```

This is the related line from logcat:
`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the bind value at index 1 is null` 
 After some tests,i figured out that I get this exception if one of the contacts have no picture set.

I searched and found [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7636) same problem. Seems like it's a bug. And I can't solve it. Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: "Don't pass in null"? Instead change the query for an explicit "IS NULL" and don't accept a parameter for it. Icky, yes, but... Happy Coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You certainly don't want to find photos with id=null, so you have to use this code:

```
if (photoId != null) {
   //your code here
}
```

Would be nice, if you posted full stack trace.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct - it is the same problem as this:

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=7636

You're also correct about it's being a bug.

The "bug" is in your code.  You need to check your arguments for "nulls", and you should NOT do a query or an update if any of your input parameters are null!

Two choices:

```
if (myphoto[i] == null)
  query.bindNull(i)
```

... or ...

```
if (myphoto[i] != null)
  query ()
```

It's YOUR responsibility to validate and clean up YOUR data before calling an API...

IMHO...